# xunit integration tests failing in devops pipeline

Tags: azure, testing, azure-pipelines, integration

.Net 5.0 solution

Local integration tests for API controllers runs without errors.

This is my fixture:

```
public class IntegrationTest
{
    protected readonly HttpClient Client;


    protected IntegrationTest()
    {
        var appFactory = new WebApplicationFactory<Startup>()
            .WithWebHostBuilder(builder =>
            {
                builder.ConfigureServices(services =>
                {         
                    services.RemoveAll(typeof(DataContext));
                    services.AddDbContext<DataContext>(options => {      options.UseInMemoryDatabase("TestDb"); });
                });
            });


        Client = appFactory.CreateClient();
    }
}
```

and the following is where I call it:

```
public class ArticleTypeControllerTests : IntegrationTest

    {
        [Theory]
        [InlineData("articletypes/Lookup")]
        public async Task Test_Should_ResultInOK(string endpoint)
        {
            var response = await Client.GetAsync(endpoint);
            response.StatusCode.Should().Be(HttpStatusCode.OK);
        }
```

However, when I include said test in my Devops pipeline they always fail.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l6LCi.png)

This is my pipeline:

```
trigger:
- Develop

pool:
  vmImage: 'windows-latest'

variables:
  solution: '**/*.sln'
  buildPlatform: 'Any CPU'
  buildConfiguration: 'Release'

steps:
- task: NuGetToolInstaller@1

- task: NuGetCommand@2
  inputs:
    restoreSolution: '$(solution)'

- task: VSBuild@1
  inputs:
    solution: '$(solution)'
    msbuildArgs: '/p:DeployOnBuild=true /p:WebPublishMethod=Package /p:PackageAsSingleFile=true /p:SkipInvalidConfigurations=true /p:DesktopBuildPackageLocation="$(build.artifactStagingDirectory)\WebApp.zip" /p:DeployIisAppPath="Default Web Site"'
    platform: '$(buildPlatform)'
    configuration: '$(buildConfiguration)'

- task: DotNetCoreCLI@2`enter code here`
  displayName: 'test'
  inputs:
    command: 'test'
    projects: '**/*tests.csproj'
    arguments: '--configuration $(buildConfiguration) --collect "Code coverage"'
```

Comment: Please format your question using https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help

Comment: @GillesEmond Were you able to resolve this issue?